# SingleResult<myObject> .ToList or .Count throws an InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a stored procedure GetTopRecords(). The sp returns the top 500 records.

1. I dragged the sp from the server explorer to the LinqtoSql designer surface.
2. I changed the return type to Record
3. In code I have:

   ```
   var x = myDataContext.GetTopRecords();
   var y = x.Count();
   var z = x.ToList();
   ```

either one of the last two lines above throws an `InvalidCastException`

the type of `x` is

```
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.SingleResult<Record>
```

Why am I getting an exception? What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: post the code for GetTopRecords(), it is really hard to see what you are returning.

Comment: What was the original return type of `GetTopRecords`?

Comment: When you are using `var`, I don't see how you can get `InvalidCastException`; strange

Comment: the sp is simple:   SELECT TOP 500 * FROM Record
  WHERE lastUpdated IS NULL

Comment: @Daniel It should be the same as the type of the inferred variable `x`, right?

Comment: @anish yes x.ToList() throws the exception. alternately, if x.count() was there before x.ToList(), the exception would also be thrown.

Comment: @Daniel, when you drap a sp on to the linq to sql design surface, the return type is (Auto-generated Type).

Comment: @Bruno: Clearly not. The type of x is `SingleResult<Record>` which is the current return type of `GetTopRecords`. According to the question, this wasn't always the case. The generated return type has been changed to the current one: "2. I changed the return type to Record"

Comment: @Hilgarth: Then you just nailed it. As I stated in the answer below, the problem is that the type returning from the method can't be cast to the type `Record`. The problem is that the OP changed the data type without regard for L2S mappings.

Comment: After reading again the question, I see that the OP did everything "right"... the query seems to return Record type... So now I'm guessing that the Record type in the L2S surface is not up-to-date... Could it be it?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I am not sure how I resolved this. But it is fixed now. If someone runs into this problem, please add a note here and I will look up my code and post the proper answer.  While I thank the responders above, unfortunately, none of the answers above helped.

Answer (score 2):

x is not a list, it is single element.  As a single element you can't convert it to a list of more than one element or count how many elements it has.

As you say "I changed the return type to Record".  Why did you do this?

Comment: If that is the case, why does ISingleElement implement the ToList and Count methods?

Comment: I'm not sure but, it has to be an Enumerable of some kind so that Count and ToList are available. Being an Enumerable, when calling ToList it should make a list with a single item and when calling Count it should return 1...

Comment: The type of x is a closure (function) that returns a Record.  Record does not have Count or ToList defined... thus the errors.

Comment: Not *a* Record. It returns a list of records. Which does have Count and ToList defined... And I don't think that is a closure. A closure is a method that references free variables (only existing on lambdas).

Comment: @Bruno - How is `System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.SingleResult<Record>` a list of records?

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I meant. It represents a SQL Procedure that return a list of records. The confusion arises from the (bad bad) choice of name *Single*. Single, in this context, doesn't means a single object, but a single *data type*. I'm searching MSDN to find the correct article, just a moment...

Comment: Here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534556.aspx. The documentation states that `SingleResult` *Represents the result of a mapped function that has a single return sequence.* The important word here is *sequence*...

Comment: @Bruno : Bingo; as you pointed out in the comments to the question, the problem is when x is executed then it will have the wrong return type.

Comment: @Hogan: Indeed, that's my guess. The OP changed the return type on his on, which is allowed (I remember doing this for SPROCS on the L2S design surface), but probably to a type that doesn't fit with the query.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is L2S (Linq To SQL), I'm assuming it's using Lazy loading, which means that only when calling `Count` or `ToList`, which are of immediate execution, the query is performed.

That said, the problem should be related to what you are returning from the `GetTopRecords` method, which isn't compatible with the `Record` type.

You should use the L2S designer to check if the result of that method is *correctly* mapped to a `Record` data type. Meaning that `Record` should be a L2S mapped table and GetTopRecords should return data from *that* table.

Answer (score 0):

Well,can you give details what GetTopRecords() .What it returns?do you need count of top records?

var x = i.ToList();
            var y = x.Count();
then it will allowed,but when ever you use tolist() ToList iterates on the query and creates an instance of List<> initialized with all the results of the query. 
which is same for count(),becuse count also need all records to perform counting.
the purpose of tolist is to prefilled data with result.

Answer (score 0):

I think there there have been changes to the database schema since the linq to sql classes were generated.  therefore there is a mismatch between the database table and the linq to Sql object representing it. therefore, the calls fail because the .NET cannot successfully cast from the db created object to the linq to sql object

Comment: The problem was indeed what I mentioned above. 

Many thanks to you all for your input.